# Firing an asp:button through Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, event-handling

I have an `asp:textbox` and an `asp:button` that submits that textbox.  I then have javascript code that creates a `div` that contains a `textarea` and an `input[type=button]`.

I want to be able to submit these created textarea's text using the `asp:button` event.  So when a user enters text within one of the `div` created textarea's and clicks the `div` `input:button`, I want to copy the textarea text to the `asp:textbox` and then call the `asp:button` click event through javascript.  I'd like to somehow pass the `id` of the `div` `input:button` into the click event of the `asp:textbox`.

How do I pass a variable to the `OnClick` event of an `asp:button` through javascript?

I've thought of using a hidden `asp:label` to store the `id`, but it seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: you know, once the page is rendered there is no such thing as an asp:button.  At that point it's just a regular old <input type="submit">

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scm" runat="server" />
<div>
   <div id="clickme" style="width: 100px; height: 50px; background-color: #CCC"
        onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$Button1', '');" />
</div>
<input type="text" name="textbox" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = Page.Request.Params["textbox"];
}
```

Note the hardcoded name of the button-id.

__doPostBack will fire a postback and the Button1_Click method gets called.

You don't need to copy the text to a asp:TextBox because you can get the content of the input field from [Page.Request.Params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params.aspx).

Edit: Don't forget to embed a [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx) when using javascript in your page.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to copy the data into server side controls?  You can always get the current HttpRequest (`HttpContext.Current.Request`) on the server side and you will have all the form data.